# Using Serial and loop to send data to Arduino slows down over time - memory leak?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

So I have some code that is pulling data from an api on a local host and then writing it over serial port to an Arduino that is powering a couple of PWM fans. Here is the code:

```
import urllib3
import serial
import json

s = serial.Serial('com4', 9600)

conn = urllib3.PoolManager()

def get_speed(conn):
    r = conn.request('GET', 'http://localhost:8180/crest2/v1/api')
    data = json.loads(r.data.decode())
    metersPerSec = int(data['carState']['mSpeed'])
    kilometersPerHour = int(metersPerSec * 3.6)
    kilometersPerHour = str(kilometersPerHour) + '\n'
    print(kilometersPerHour)
    s.write((kilometersPerHour.encode()))
    s.flush()

running=True
while running:
    get_speed(conn)
```

I need this code to read from the API and write over serial to an arduino very quickly (multiple times per second).  When I start the script it runs snappy and calls the api many times a second as expected, but after a few seconds it slows down and only makes calls every one second or so. I assume this is due to some sort of memory leak or misuse of the while loop but I am not informed enough to fix my issue.

Any help or guidance to a similar issue would be much appreciated as I have spent days searching and trying different things to optimize.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you filing up a buffer in the serial link? One obvious test is remove the network request and just send a fixed set of data. Ten disable the serial and just do the network request - in case the server is doing some sort of request rate limiting

Comment: @MartinBeckett Thanks for taking a look.  When I comment out the `serial.write()` lines there is no slow down.  How could I work on fixing the serial buffer?  Should I just slow down my write calls with a `time.sleep` to make sure the arduino can handle what I throw at it?

Comment: If you don't have a way of signalling that the arduino is ready then yes, just limit the rate to 1/sec or whatever makes sense for your application

Answer (score 0):

```
s = serial.Serial('com4', 9600)
```

Try running at a faster baud rate.  9600 is a snails pace and your transmit buffer is filling up.  Once that happens then the next write has to block until there is room in the buffer for what it wants to write.